# PowerPDF API - Converting VB Code to C# - Error HRESULT E_FAIL

Tags: c#, vb.net, pdf

I am trying to convert the following VB code to C#.  The code runs without breaking in VB but breaks on the line indicated in C#.  The code is straightforward.  It uses a program called PowerPDF to open a PDF document and then uses javascript to display an alert.

**VB Code - This runs without error**

```
Sub Main()

     Dim dvOpenDoc = CreateObject("PowerPDF.DVDoc")
     dvOpenDoc.Open("C:\TestFiles\SampleFormSource.pdf")

     Dim ddDoc = dvOpenDoc.GetDDDoc()
     Dim jso = ddDoc.GetJSObject

     jso.app.alert("Show this alert")

End Sub
```

**C# Code - This breaks on the line indicated**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Type GetPDFType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("PowerPDF.DVDoc");
        dynamic dvOpenDoc = Activator.CreateInstance(GetPDFType);
        dvOpenDoc.Open(@"C:\TestFiles\SampleFormSource.pdf");

        var ddDoc = dvOpenDoc.GetDDDoc();
        dynamic jso = ddDoc.GetJSObject();

        //I have also tried these
        //var jso = ddDoc.GetJSObject;
        //dynamic jso = ddDoc.GetJSObject;
        //var jso = ddDoc.GetJSObject();

        //The program always breaks on the following line. 
        //Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
        jso.app.alert("Show this alert");


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I have tried running both snippets on two different development machines using VS 2017 with the same result: C# fails, VB works.  Both are .Net Framework 4.6.1.

I did notice that in the VB version (the one that runs without any issues) that when I insert a breakpoint and inspect the jso object I can see an error in the Dynamic View as pictured below.

[image: VB Code Breakpoint]

However, this does not seem to affect the function of the program.  It runs to completion and does what I want: Opens the PDF and displays an alert.

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: If you have vb.net code with CreateObject(), something already went wrong a long time ago

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn that code (or something close to it) was provided in an example by the vendor.  It may relate to an earlier version of VB.  The reason it is included here is that it is working.  I would rather have this in C#, hence the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can't test with PowerPDF that I don't have but I faced the same issue with the Adobe's Acrobat SDK itself (I guess this PowerPDF uses Acrobat SDK undercovers).

Anyway, in the Acrobat case, the C# `dynamic` "pseudo-type" doesn't work because the underlying object implementing COM Automation [IDispatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch) always fails (and actually causes a crash in Acrobat process...) when we call [GetTypeInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nf-oaidl-idispatch-gettypeinfo), which is what `dynamic` does in its implementation.

The solution is to use what we did before `dynamic` existed: use direct [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) techniques like this (you may have to adapt it slightly to PowerPDF):

```
  static void Main()
  {
      Type GetPDFType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("AcroExch.PDDoc");
      dynamic dvOpenDoc = Activator.CreateInstance(GetPDFType);
      dvOpenDoc.Open(@"C:\TestFiles\SampleFormSource.pdf");

      object jso = dvOpenDoc.GetJSObject(); // note I use object type here, not dynamic!

      // these reflection calls are equivalent to jso.app.alert("Show this alert");

      // get the "app" property
      var app = jso.GetType().InvokeMember("app", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Public, null, jso, null);

      // call the "alert" method (has 1 argument)
      app.GetType().InvokeMember("alert", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public, null, app, new[] { "Show this alert" });
      return;
  }
```